# Atan2 function unwrap

Tags: plotting, trigonometry

I use *atan2* function in my calculations. The results are as follows:

[image]

Matlab has the **unwrap** function, and it copes well with the correction of such plots.

How to do it in Mathematica?

Comment: It is not clear how this plot was made (no code is shown).

Comment: The code is very long. I will try to explain in words. There are two parameters T1 (t) and T2 (t), they change in time. According to them, these graphs are calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Wolfram Function Repository function **PhaseUnwrap**: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PhaseUnwrap

Note that this only works with numerical data, not with functions. Without any specifics on your data I can't make an example for you.

Comment: In my case, atan2 is simply a time-dependent function, and is calculated through the parameters T1 (t) and T2 (t). The figure shows a graph of this function. This is not a vector or a selection of data.

Comment: Generate the plot points using Table or so and then pass it through PhaseUnwrap before plotting it using ListPlot.

Comment: `data = Table[\[Theta]1, {t, 1, 21}]`

`unwrapped = ResourceFunction["PhaseUnwrap"][data];
Column[{
  ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Joined -> False, PlotLabel -> "Original data"],
  ListPlot[unwrapped, Frame -> True, Joined -> False, PlotLabel -> "Corrected data"] }]`

I get the error: "Failed [data] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers."



\[Theta]1 - this is one of the functions whose graph I built.

Comment: What does unwrapped look like?

Comment: I expected the same result that is presented on the site when clicking on the link.

Comment: The Table does not give any numbers, on the website of PhaseUnwrap it gives a bunch of datapoints rather than the table. Try something like: ```ListPlot[ResourceFunction["PhaseUnwrap"][Table[Mod[t, 2 Pi], {t, 0, 100}]]]```